# Different Python outputs with Signal Fourier Transform

Tags: python, fft

I am trying to run a Python `STFT` (also known as a Short-Time Fourier Transform) on two identically sampled pieces of data.

However, due to one of my applications of the data, I need some of it to be collected into a `.txt` file.

I am confused as to why the STFT would be working for the data that is coming in from the `.csv`, and not producing a correct output for the data that is coming in from the `.txt` file.  Both are `Panda.core.series.Series` data types, and both have values on similar magnitudes.  The testing conditions were identical as well.

The code that I am trying to troubleshoot is the code labeled, `Code that isn't returning the expected output`.  Any insights or observations would be greatly appreciated!

Note that I have the line `result[::4]` because I had to get rid of 3 out of every 4 samples, to match the sampling rates between the two data acquisition methods.

**Code that isn't returning the expected output:**

```
import json
result = []
with open("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\data.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        result.append(json.loads(line)[-1])
result = result[::4]
result = pd.Series(result)

f, t, Zxx = scipy.signal.stft(result, fs=500, nperseg = 1000)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.pcolormesh(t, f, np.abs(Zxx), vmin=0, vmax=0.001)
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.show()
```

**Code that is functioning properly:**

```
test = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Documents\\data.csv")
test.head()
test.columns = ['TS', 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4']

f, t, Zxx = scipy.signal.stft(test['Col1'], fs=500, nperseg = 1000)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.pcolormesh(t, f, np.abs(Zxx), vmin=0, vmax=0.001)
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You need to use a low pass filter before decimating. [Decimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimation_(signal_processing)): "Downsampling alone causes high-frequency signal components to be misinterpreted by subsequent users of the data, which is a form of distortion called aliasing."

Comment: Makes sense.  How should I determine the frequency for which to create the lowpass filter for?

Comment: And then how would I take the low-passed output and plug it back into my STFT?

Comment: Since you are decimating by 4, you need a filter that has significant attenuation at 1/4 the original frequency. When I was writing DSP software, we used [FIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response) filters with -60 dB attenuation at the cutoff frequency. After filtering, you decimate (sub-samble) and run the result through the [STFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to replace

```
result = result[::4]
```

with

```
result = scipy.signal.decimate(result, 4, ftype='fir')
```

I specified `'fir'` for the filter type because FIR filters have linear phase delay. This may or may not be important in your situation.